# Start-Job not returning custom class object properly when PSCustomObject returns as intended

Tags: powershell

I'm running into a problem that isn't really a hindrance, but a possible bug from serialization in extracting job output (guessing?). The code below is a snippet from Start-Job and later captured output by foreach (Start-Job | Receive-Job)

```
class ComputerResult {
    $computerName
    $bldg
    $room
    $organization
    $user
    $lastUpdate
    $printerlist = @()
    $finalprinterlist = @()
}
# This one below doesn't work.    
$return_result = New-Object -TypeName ComputerResult

# This done does work.
$return_result = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{ComputerName = ""; BLDG = ""; room = ""; organization = ""; user = ""; lastupdate = ""; printerlist = @(); finalprinterlist = @() }

# Here I would start assigning values to $return_result

# Once assigned, return from the Job process to await Receive-Job
return $return_result
```

The main issue is the `$return_result` where it works as intended when it's a type `PSCustomObject`, unlike the `ComputerResult` class object defined above it. When the script runs, a `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_printer -ComputerName $computername` Is done to add some WMI objects into my `$return_result.printerlist`, but when returned, the `ComputerResult.printerlist` is returning an array of strings - with values of the `__PATH` property. What should be returned is WMI objects.

`PSCustomObject` returns just fine with keeping its methods, properties, etc. The `ComputerResult.printerlist` is kept with full WMI objects.

My assumption is the PSCustomObject is handled differently from the rest of the custom classes, in some way, and perhaps uses a different underlying library when serializing and piping back into the main process.

Why is this? Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?  I ran the code you posted on PSVersion 5.1.14393.3383 on Server 2016, and had no problem getting $return_result as TypeName: ComputerResult.

Comment: Powershell version 5.1.17763.771, did you run a WMI for win32_printer and add it to the list? The Class object array is the important part here.

Comment: I did.  See Answer below for code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function with your code like this:

```
Function RetPrinter
{
    class ComputerResult {
        $computerName
        $bldg
        $room
        $organization
        $user
        $lastUpdate
        $printerlist = @()
        $finalprinterlist = @()
    }

    $return_result = New-Object -TypeName ComputerResult
    $return_result.PrinterList += gwmi win32_printer
    return $return_result
}
```

I then retrieved my printer list like so:

```
$Obj = RetPrinter
```

By piping them to `gm`, $Obj was returned as TypeName:ComputerResult, and $ObjName.PrinterList was seen as TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_Printer.  All seemed to work as expected.

Comment: I would expect everything to work properly from a function itself. Try doing it with Start-Job and making the job return the ComputerResult object with WMI objects inside the printerlist array

Comment: That's a bit of work to frame in a Start-Job.  Do you have a code snippet for the Job?

Comment: Deleted my previous comment to try and get this comment working.
`Get-WmiObject -Class win32_printer -ComputerName $compnamehere`

After that, I'd filter and then add objects to the `$return_result.printerlist`

However, this needs to be inside a job. Inside `-scriptblock` of the job. This MUST be multi-threaded. I have too many computers.

Comment: Well...I put that in a file, and started that with Start-Job.  Good/Bad news was that I was able to reproduce your issue.  Worse news is I have no freakin' idea why it is coming back as an array of strings and not the wmi objects.  I might have to dig into this deeper...very curious.  If the problem is the return-by-job mechanism though, you might do better by having the jobs write their data to a local log file with `$return_value | export-clixml -depth n -path localfilepath.clixml` which you can then later collect.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. I don't expect an answer anytime soon, but it's bothersome the behavior is so different.